# Factory method 'tomcatReactiveWebServerFactory' threw exception with message: jakarta/servlet/Servlet

Tags: spring-webflux

I have the following in my build.gradle:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent
implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:3.0.2')

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.0.2")

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-webflux
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:3.0.2")
```

But I get the following exception on startup.

```
Factory method 'tomcatReactiveWebServerFactory' threw exception with message: jakarta/servlet/Servlet
```

What dependency am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like commenting out the following additional dependency is removing the above error:

```
implementation('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.0.2')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).